# Trouble with populating an array

Tags: javascript

It's very basic, but I just don't see what I'm missing here..

Consider the next array `objects`. It needs to be filled with instances of `object` which each have their own `id`:

```
var objects= [];
var object= {};

object.id = 1;
objects[0] = object;
object.id = 2;
objects[1] = object;
object.id = 3;
objects[2] = object;
```

When I alert the first object with `alert(objects[0].id)`, it says `3`.
Again, what am I missing here?

Comment: `object` is always one and the same object. You are only updating its `id` property and assign it two three different locations in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It save the object as reference so as soon as you change the id, it changes it for everything.
To solve it you can simply do

```
object.id = 1;
objects[0] = object;
object = {};
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! :)

Answer (score 7):

This is because you are pushing the *same* object into each spot in the array.  You need to make new ones each time.

```
var objects = [];

objects[0] = {id: 1};
objects[1] = {id: 2};
objects[2] = {id: 3};
```

Or better yet, just make it all at once:

```
var objects = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3},
];
```

Comment: @mori57: Yeah... that's what I get for copying and pasting :-P

Comment: Thanks alot! Both answers are good, bt Shryme's fits my needs more as I need multiple instances of object to store data from the website. And he can use the points more than you can ;)!